# How to resolve: Error when bootstrapping CMake on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, installation

I received an error while trying to build CMake on Linux. I could not reach the `make` step. I read around the web but still couldn't really fix this.

I tried both of these, but neither worked:

```sh
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/cmake

$ ./bootstrap
```

They resulted in:

```sh
CMake Error at CmakeLists.txt:107 (message):
The C++ compiler does not support C++11 (e.g. std::unique_ptr).

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred
--------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running initial CMake
--------------------------------------------
```

And:

```sh
command -v g++
/usr/bin/g++

g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
```

The code I am trying to compile is in C, so I'm wondering why I'm receiving errors raised with respect to the C++ Compiler? Perhaps any thoughts on this too?

Comment: The error message is self-explanatoring: CMake treats your compiler as not supporting c++11. If you think CMake is wrong, you need to provide more details about your compiler (probably, `g++`). E.g. its version.

Comment: Hope this is what you're looking for

`
C++ compiler on the system is : g++
Markfile processor on this system is: make
g++ has setenv
g++ has unsetenv
g++ does not have environ in stdlib.h
g++ has stl wstring
g++ has <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
`

Comment: Can you explain why you are compiling  CMake from source? It is readily available in all package managers. *definitely* in ubuntu 18.04!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install cmake` is probably the easiest fix, unless you need something bleeding edge or bug fix from CMake. It sounds like Linaro C++ headers are not on-path. I've seen this in the past, but not recently. You could try the Clang compiler. Or try adding `CXXFLAGS="-I /usr/include/c++/7"`. Maybe something like: `CXXFLAGS="-I /usr/include/c++/7" ./bootstrap`. Also see [g++-arm-linux-gnueabi cannot compile a C++ program with --sysroot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults-armel-cross/+bug/1375071) (and friends).

Comment: I am actually installing cmake from a NVIDIA device without internet connection (rather tedious setup). wondering if that is possible.

Comment: @jww You need a working cmake to compile clang, bit of a chicken egg situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the specific gcc and g++ version using the following commands.

```
export CC=path_of_gcc/gcc-version
export CXX=path_of_g++/g++-version
```

And now run any of the commands:

```
./configure    #OR
./bootstrap
```